# How to Create different user/Member types in Python Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

I need to create a paid  memebership website with django.There are three types of members to be registered. these registration form/model will have different form fields appart from common authentication fields. In the admin panel these  member/users should be listed separately from the super user/ admin/staff users. how can I achive this?

## models.py

```
from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from .constants import GENDER_CHOICES, RADIO_CHOICES, INDIAN_STATES,COUNTRIES, DISTRICTS_IN_KERALA


class MemberType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class NurseMemberManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class NurseMember(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Add other fields as needed

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    whatsapp_no = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    address_lene_1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    address_lene_2 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    nursing_reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    employed = models.BooleanField(choices=RADIO_CHOICES,default=True,)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=COUNTRIES, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=INDIAN_STATES, blank=True,  null=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DISTRICTS_IN_KERALA, blank=True,  null=True)
    hospital = models.CharField( max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    membership_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # True if the user has an active membership
    creation_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def expiry_date(self):
        if self.creation_date:
            # Calculate the expiry date by adding one year to the creation_date
            expiry_date = self.creation_date + timedelta(days=365)
            return expiry_date
        return None
    
    
    objects = NurseMemberManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    
    def full_name(self):
        if self.is_superuser:
            return self.email
        else:
            return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def __uniceode__(self):
        return self.full_name 





class StudentMember(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    gender_choices = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender_choices)

    def full_name(self):
        if self.is_superuser:
            return self.email
        else:
            return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"




class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('NurseMember', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import NurseMember


class NurseForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NurseMember

        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'mobile_no', 'whatsapp_no', 'pin_code', 'nursing_reg_no','address_lene_1', 'address_lene_2', 'country', 'state', 'district', 'hospital',
        'password1', 'password2')

        RADIO_CHOICES = [
        (True, 'Working'),
        (False, 'Not Working'),
        ]
       

        widgets = {
            'date_of_birth': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'employed': forms.RadioSelect(choices=RADIO_CHOICES)
        }
        
    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['email'].required = True

     


    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()
        new = NurseMember.objects.filter(username = username)
        if new.count():
            raise forms.ValidationError("User already Exist")
        return username
    
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        new = NurseMember.objects.filter(email = email)
        if new.count():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already Exist")
        return email
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password1 = cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            self.add_error('password2', "The passwords do not match")

        return cleaned_data


        
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

#admin.py

```
`# Register your models here.
@admin.register(NurseMember)
class NurseMemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= [ 'full_name', 'email','membership_status']`
```

I am beginer of Django.  Please help me.
`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.